# When saving a form in Orbeon Form Builder I get an error

Tags: database, orbeon, exist-db

I downloaded Orbeon CE and followed this tutorial to install it http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-Software-requirements
I am using Apache Tomcat.

I could open orbeon on my browser and also create and test a form without problems. The error I encounter is when I want to save it:

```
"Unable to complete action
There was an error communicating with the database. Please contact the application administrator."
```

I read [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/exist-configuration) that "By default, Orbeon Forms ships with an embedded eXist database."

This is the the log of localhost I find:

> 2-set-2013 19.01.16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   GRAVE: Allocate exception for servlet exist-rest-servlet
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: No database instance available
>       at org.exist.http.servlets.EXistServlet.init(EXistServlet.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Can someone help me?

Update:

Here the exist-conf.xml:

```
<db-connection cacheSize="20M" collectionCache="10M" database="native" files="exist-data" pageSize="4096" nodesBuffer="-1">
```

I tried also to install eXist database but nothing.

Comment: Discussion going on [here](http://discuss.orbeon.com/When-saving-a-form-in-Orbeon-Form-Builder-I-get-an-error-td4657239.html).

Comment: @Colet Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue in windows.